# How to Individually Reference Each Thumb of a RangeSlider (ControlsFX)

Tags: javafx, rangeslider, controlsfx

I'm trying to bind a label to be displayed above the lower and upper thumbs of [RangeSlider](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html).

The label's position should always remain above their respective thumb, no matter where the user slides it. Like so:

[image]

[image]

My approach is to attach listeners to each thumb so that I can set the label's to have appropriate X/Y coordinates every time a user slides. But when I run the following code I can't seem to get a reference to the individuals thumbs, via css selectors.

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221734/3851150), but this only uses one thumb and is therefore easy to reference. How do you properly use CSS selectors in my context, or what is a better approach if mine is flawed?

**Controller**

```
public class SliderDemoController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private RangeSlider range;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Pane thumb = (Pane) range.lookup(".range-slider .low-thumb");
        System.out.println(thumb); // <-- Prints null
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class SliderDemoMain extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage initStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Drag.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sliderdemo.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Slider Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**styleMain.css**

```
.range-slider .range-bar {
    -fx-background-color: grey;
}

.range-slider .low-thumb {
     //....
}
.range-slider .high-thumb {
    //....
}
```

**Top Line of sliderdemo.fxml**

```
<HBox fx:id="menuBar" maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="79.0" stylesheets="@styleMain.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.propertydrop.SliderDemoController">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For CSS lookups to work, you need CSS to have been applied, a layout pass to have been made, and the node to be part of a scene. (Note this in the post you referenced, the code in the answer carefully performs these steps before performing the lookup.)

This is difficult to achieve in a controller, because the `initialize()` method is typically invoked before the root node from the FXML is added to a scene. You can hack this by observing the `sceneProperty()` of the node, and responding when it is set to something non-null. (Yes, this is a bit of a hack...):

```
public class SliderDemoController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private RangeSlider range;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ChangeListener<Scene> initializer = new ChangeListener<Scene>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> obs, Scene oldScene, Scene newScene)  {
                if (newScene != null) {
                    range.applyCss();
                    range.getParent().layout();
                    Pane thumb = (Pane) range.lookup(".range-slider .low-thumb");
                    System.out.println(thumb); // <-- No longer null
                    range.sceneProperty().removeListener(this);
                }
            }
        };
        range.sceneProperty().addListener(initializer);
    }
}
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you might be able to get away with something a little less ugly, such as performing the lookup in an event handler or a listener on the slider's `highValue` or `lowValue` properties.

Comment: Personally, I don't see this as a hack. I can only say that this is necessary because the API doesn't provide a "shortcut" out of the box. Just be glad there is even a solution for it :)

Comment: @Jai It's a hack :). The "API-correct" way to do what you're trying to do would be to create a new skin for the `RangeSlider` that included the labels you want to show. However, since (at present) the skin class is not public, this would involve re-inventing the wheel and be a lot of work.

Comment: @James_D, so long as this hack is reliable in a commercial context, I'm fine with the aesthetics. You've answered my question, thank you. Performing the lookup within a `range.lowValueProperty().addListener` indeed is sufficient. +1